# JNA library path seems to be ignored

Tags: java, c++, jna

I'm trying to specify the library load path for JNA on linux for a C++ library.
From the java doc I used `-Djna.library.path` when calling my program but JNA fails to load the library.

This is how I call the program:

```
java -jar -Djna.library.path=/home/lib program.jar
```

When I use `-Djna.debug_load=true` I can see the library path and JNA trying to find the library, the path is correct and the library name is also correct, but it doesn't load. JNA continues to search the resource path for the library and then fails to find it.

When I put the library in the current directory (same level as program.jar) JNA is happy and the library is loaded without issue.

When I use:

```
java -cp program.jar:/home/lib package.program
```

JNA also loads the correct library.

Does anyone here know why `-Djna.library.path` does not work? Is it because I'm using a jar application file with a manifest?

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: Can you include the code you use to load the library?

Comment: Possibly the same as this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829764/jna-native-library-dependencies-and-jar-extraction

Comment: An answer elsewhere states:  DLL loading is done by OS and if the DLLs are stored inside a jar, then they must be extracted somewhere into the (Windows) file system before they can be loaded.

Comment: This is the code I use:

public interface LibNative extends Library {
    LibNative depLib = (LibNative) Native.loadLibrary("shared", LibNative.class);

    LibNative INSTANCE = (LibNative) Native.loadLibrary("native", LibNative.class);
}

Comment: libnative.so is the library containing the C wrapper code, which is called from Java. libshared.so is the dependancy library required by libnative.so

The libraries are not included in program.jar. They are in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that once you leave JVM, jna.library.path or java.library.path is no longer taken into account.

Make sure to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH such way it points to locations where libshared.so is located.

Update:

Take a look here to check how using code from shared lib works:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo023

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying if I run it like this -> java -jar -Djna.library.path=/home/lib program.jar then it doesn't work and I have to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH??

Comment: Yes, try with that. Start with setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to location where your so file is. Also, double check whether all libraries, that your C++ codes depend on, are also available for JVM.