# How to load native libraries in AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In my java serverless project I have to call a native library for image processing (`libvips`). I am using Gradle to create a zip file and sending to the lib folder all the dependencies, including the native libraries:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
archiveName = "${project.name}.zip"
from compileJava
from processResources
from('.') {
    include 'lib/**'
    include 'bin/**'
}
into('lib') {
    from configurations.runtime
}
}
```

In the generated zip file, in the `lib` folder all the libraries are there (jars/native/etc).

After deploying the function through `serverless deploy` I am not able to load the `libvips.so` library using `Native.loadLibrary("/var/task/lib/libvips.so", Object.class)`. Apparently in `/var/task/lib/` are located only java dependencies and not the native libraries.

Is there another path where AWS stores native libraries?

**EDIT**

Exception being thrown:

```
ava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/var/task/lib/libvips.so': Native library (var/task/lib/libvips.so) not found in resource path ([file:/var/task/, file:/var/task/lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar, file:/var/task/lib/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar, file:/var/task/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.336.jar, file:/var/task/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.336.jar, file:/var/task/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.336.jar, file:/var/task/lib/aws-lambda-java-core-1.1.0.jar,....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify [`java.library.path`](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/) JVM property.

By modifying JVM command line options

```
 JAVA_OPTS = $JAVA_OPS -Djava.library.path= /var/task/lib/ 
 java $JAVA_OPTS ...
```

Or modify it  directly in your code

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/var/task/lib/");
System.loadLibrary("libvips.so");
```

Also, you can use [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) library. JNA provides functionality to auto-unpack and load native librarians from the JAR archive (resources) added to the JVM class path. It's includes selecting correct operating system and CPU architecture version binaries.

Comment: thanks, I have already set the library path in serverless.yml, the problem is that the native libraries are not being stored there. Only jars are there

Comment: also I am using JNA to call the native library

Comment: Check this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829764/jna-native-library-dependencies-and-jar-extraction?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Also check that UNIX user (user which starts you app server) able to write to and execute code from `/var/task/lib/`, as well as check that libvips.so have execute file attribute.

Comment: Ofc it has, it is reading from this path, only that the native libraries are not there. That's why I would like to know if these libraries are stored in some other path..

Comment: You can simply call to `Native.loadLibrary("libvips.so", NativeLibInteface.class);` . And you can use  `JAVA_OPTS = $JAVA_OPS -Djna.tmpdir=/var/task/lib/` to replace default temporary directory to your's directory.

Comment: Tried this, its not working, I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Strange enough 'System.loadLibrary("lib/libvips.so");' works. I am marking your question as the right one, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not all native libraries are present in lambda environment, you have to make a custom deployment package using either a docker or Ec2.

here is how you will do that :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-java